# Kick off SSRS report by report name instead of GUID

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Just wondering if it is possible to kick off a series of different SSRS reports in a stored proc by report name instead of the guid.

For example, from within the body of the procedure:
    exec {servername}.msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'SSRS Report Name Here'

instead of:
    exec {servername}.msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'F589B96A-EEFB-488D-9D1C-FE05C585598B'

Answer (score 0):

Yes Here are the parameters for sp_start_job:

```
sp_start_job   
     {   [@job_name =] 'job_name'  
       | [@job_id =] job_id }  
     [ , [@error_flag =] error_flag]  
     [ , [@server_name =] 'server_name']  
     [ , [@step_name =] 'step_name']  
     [ , [@output_flag =] output_flag]
```

You must provide @job_name or @job_id.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the ReportServer database, you can find the job name (which is also a uniqueidentifier) against the report name.

```
DECLARE @SubscriptionID SYSNAME

SELECT @SubscriptionID = RS.ScheduleID
FROM [ReportSchedule] RS
INNER JOIN [Catalog] C ON RS.ReportID = C.ItemID
WHERE C.[Name] = '<Report Name Here>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @SubscriptionID
```